# Test cases development for filter query search in Django

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-tests

I am testing a Django Library application, which has a Book model and a **search bar to filter those books** that checks title__icontains = 'q'.

The **url pattern**:

```
path('search_book/', views.BookSearchListView.as_view(), name='search_book'),
```

The url routing:

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/search_book/?q=house
```

Implementation of the following **Class-based view**:

```
class BookSearchListView(BookListView):
  paginate_by = 3

  def get_queryset(self):
    result = super(BookSearchListView, self).get_queryset()

    query = self.request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        query_list = query.split()
        result = result.filter(
            reduce(operator.and_,
                   (Q(title__icontains=q) for q in query_list))
        )

    return result
```

In my `tests.py`, I have to develop test cases for the above view, but do not understand how to go about it. I have attempted the following:

```
class BookSearchListViewTest(TestCase):
"""
        Test case for the Book Search List View
"""
   def setUp(self):
    test_user1 = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser1', password='1X<ISRUkw+tuK')
    test_user1.save()

    test_author = Author.objects.create(first_name='John', last_name='Smith')
    Book.objects.create(title='House', author=test_author, summary='Published in 1990',
                        isbn='123456789123')
    Book.objects.create(title='Money', author=test_author, summary='Published in 1991',
                        isbn='9876543210123')
    Book.objects.create(title='Mouse', author=test_author, summary='Published in 1992',
                        isbn='1293874657832')

   def test_redirect_if_not_logged_in(self):
    response = self.client.get(reverse('books'))
    self.assertRedirects(response, '/catalog/customer_login/?next=/catalog/books/')

   def test_query_search_filter(self):
    self.assertQuerysetEqual(Book.objects.filter(title__icontains='House'), ["<Book: House>"])
```

While the test_query_search_filter test runs successfully, in my coverage report, the class BookSearchListView is not getting tested.

I am a complete novice in Django and have just started out with test cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you have parameter in your url then you should send it via `url` in your test case.

You created a `Book` object which title is `House` in your `setUp` method so;

```
  def test_query_filter(self):
     # If you have login required to access 'books' then
     # you have to login with 'client.login' first.
     url = '{url}?{filter}={value}'.format(
        url=reverse('books'),
        filter='q', value='Hou')
     # With string format finally we expect a url like;
     # '/books/q=Hou'
     self.client.login(username='testuser1', password='1X<ISRUkw+tu')
     response = self.client.get(url)
     ...
     # test cases
     ...
```

Comment: Your input code works perfectly, the test is successful, however the class-based view BookSearchListView(BookListView) is not getting tested (as per coverage report)

Comment: `BookSearchListView` this view registered as `search_book` so, did you change `books` to `search_book`?

Comment: can you try with `reverse('search_book')`?

Comment: yes I tried 'search_book', and that test also runs successfully, but the coverage tool still indicates that the class-based view is not getting tested

Answer (score 0):

You can test it like this:

```
def test_redirect_if_not_logged_in(self):
    self.client.login(username='testuser1', password='1X<ISRUkw+tu')
    response = self.client.get(reverse('books'))
    self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['object_list'], Book.objects.all(), transform= lambda x:x)
```

You can check the [testing tools documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/) for more details.

Comment: It receives the Error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: can you share your full stacktrace please?